# 8th Grade Geometry Math Problem, 3->1 postulates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nge0u.png]

There are $6$ propositions:

> 1. $AD\parallel BC$
> 2. $E$ is the midpoint of $CD$
> 3. $AE$ bisects $\angle BAD$
> 4. $BE$ bisects $\angle ABC$
> 5. $AB=AD+BC$
> 6. $AE\bot BE$

The question is to prove that given any $3$ propositions, you can prove any other proposition. Assume that $D$, $E$, and $C$ are in a line.

Admittedly, this is a homework question, but the original question asks to prove one set of ($3$ propositions $\Rightarrow1$ other). However, the original question implied that any set is doable.

I already have $123, 124, 125, 126, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146$ down (the sets where propositions $1, 2,$ and $3$ are given, and we are asked to prove the rest is called $123$).

I have not tried most of the others, but they seem hard. Any solutions / hints?

TBD:

- <s>156</s>
- <s>234</s>
- 235
- 236
- 256
- 345
- 346
- 356

I have omitted $245, 246, 456$ because they are the same as $235, 236, 356,$ respectively.

Comment: @InanimateBeing do we really have to (use MathJax for pure numbers)?

Comment: xxxxnjmmmmmmm

@NumberBasher No, but using it is like adding serif and light bold, so it has to be used in formatting where need is required. Your usage is justified.

Comment: OK Thanks, good to know @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$156$ do not imply the others, see counterexample below.

[image]

$234$ do not imply the others, see counterexample below.

[image]